# Trying to open web browser in python script executed via service (linux)

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome, linux-mint, python-webbrowser

I'm trying to use webbrowser in simple python script (just open url) on Linux Mint 20.3 but it is NOT so easy as it was on windows 10...

```
webbrowser.get('/usr/bin/google-chrome %s %U --disable-setuid-sandbox --no-sandbox').open('http://google.com')
```

results in the following error:

```
ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)

ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)

ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(307)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!

Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
```

This script is supposed to run via service (systemctl) on startup and so I have to use --no-sandbox flag because otherwise chromium is not happy. Do you know if there is a simple way of fixing errors listed above? Thanks in advance

CHROME VERSION 97.0.4692.71 64Bit

Comment: Did you try to remove `--disable-setuid-sandbox --no-sandbox` ?

Comment: @GonzaloOdiard Hi, yes, I tried that and then only these 2 cpufreq errors appear. But still, how do I fix them?

Answer (score 0):

This works on my linux environment

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com')
```

About starting the script with systemctl, you need have a windowing system already started. Something like
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388837/systemd-run-script-after-gui-is-ready